# How to boot an HP XW8000 from a USB flash drive?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, usb

I have an old XW8000 machine that I’ve been trying and failing boot from USB flash drive for the last week.

I’ve tried burning Ubuntu 6.0, 8.0, 14.0, 22.04 on USB media using PowerIso and BalenaEtcher and the usb is just not being booted from on the machine. I thought maybe it was the type of file system so I changed from FAT, FAT32, NTFS. Didn’t work.

So then I burned the .iso to CD drive and system booted right up. I went to BIOS and looked at every option to allow boot from USB and tried enabling it, still nothing. I even tried pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> on boot up and manually forcing the computer to boot from removable media- still nothing.

Comment: "Refurbishing" old computers is laudable - reduces e-waste - and retrocomputing can be fun as an hobby. That said it takes a lot more knowledge, experience and patience. The way you posted this question shows a concerning lack of at least the first two.

Answer (score 1):

Given its age, this computer in unlikely to support USB Storage as a bootable device.

The [Technical Manual](https://www.compeve.com/Documents/HP%20xw8000/HP_xw8000_techical_compeve.pdf) also makes no mention of USB being a bootable source.

In the BIOS, find the BOOT MENU list, let us know what options you have available, and we'll let you know if any of them are likely candidates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PLOP Boot Manager](https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/plpbt.bin.html#runcd) to create a bootable CD and use it to chainload to your USB live/installation media.

**Important note #1**: The HP XW8000 should run with acceptable performance any currently supported mainstream Linux with lightweight Desktop Environments and provided you won't run demanding software. As such, DON'T even try out of support Ubuntu releases as you've doing. At the time of this writing choose an Ubuntu flavor like [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/downloads/) and one of the supported releases ONLY!

Alternatively you may try other Linux distros geared towards old computers like [AntiX Linux](https://antixlinux.com/).

**Import note #2**: Unfortunately the old Nvidia Quadro NVS280 will have to run with the community open-source driver `nouveau` because the last Nvidia proprietary driver supporting legacy graphics cards such as yours was release 10 years ago and cannot be installed with the current kernel branches.